# How to save selected language in local storage or cookies in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angularjs. I need to save the language selected from a select tab in html, in local storage or cookies, that when user navigates to another page, the new page opened load and use the language selected in previous page. 
Like now, if change page or just refresh the current page, selected language disappear and user must select it agin.
I used bower components for angular js, and load translation from static files.

1. Here is my Html code:

```html
<div >
    <section class="caret">
      <h4>Select language for translation:</h4>
      <select class="caret" ng-change="translate()" ng-model="selectedLanguage">
        <option class="caret" value="en">English</option>
        <option class="caret" value="no">Norsk</option>
      </select>
    </section>
<div>
```

2. My app

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
```

3. My controller

```js
app.controller('myController',['$scope', 'translationService', 

function ($scope, translationService){  

  //Run translation if selected language changes
  $scope.translate = function(){
       translationService.getTranslation($scope, $scope.selectedLanguage);
   };
   
   //Init
   $scope.selectedLanguage = 'en';
   $scope.translate();
   
}]);
```

4. My translation service

```js
app.service('translationService', function($resource) {  

        this.getTranslation = function($scope, language) {
            var languageFilePath = 'translation_' + language + '.json';
            console.log(languageFilePath);
            $resource(languageFilePath).get(function (data) {
                $scope.translation = data;
            });
   
   
        };
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `localStorage`. As long as you just need String-Key-Value-Pairs, you'll be fine using it just like below.

Once you need to persist Objects and the like, you could use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to serialize them.

Here's your updated code, see the comments:
    app.controller('myController',['$scope', 'translationService',

```
function ($scope, translationService){  

  $scope.translate = function(){
       translationService.getTranslation($scope, $scope.selectedLanguage);

       //Save changes to localStorage
       localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', $scope.selectedLanguage);
   };

   //Init
     //Set initial value or default
     $scope.selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage') || 'en';
   $scope.translate();

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much JanS, that work just fine. it was more simple than i expected. Now, when i open a new page or refresh the current one, the selected language remain.

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer helped you, please accept it.